# MySQL SUM() agrupando por un mismo ID en diferentes columnas

Tags: mysql

Este es el problema a resolver:

Tengo una tabla, en la cual se registran desde 1 hasta 5 diferentes productos, pero no hay un control de orden al registrar los productos, en un registro un producto puede estar en el campo product_1 y en otro registro puede estar en el campo product_5, esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
    *-----------------++
    |ID                |
    |DATE              |
    |ID_PRODUCT_1      |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1|
    |ID_PRODUCT_2      |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2|
    |ID_PRODUCT_3      |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3|
    |ID_PRODUCT_4      |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4|
    |ID_PRODUCT_5      |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5|
    +------------------+
```

Estos son unos registros de ejemplo, de lo que acabo de explicar:

```
    *--------------------------------+
    |ID                 = 1          |
    |DATE               = 2017-02-03 |
    |ID_PRODUCT_1       = 1001       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1 = 1400       |
    |ID_PRODUCT_2       = 1002       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2 = 600        |
    |ID_PRODUCT_3       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3 = -          |
    |ID_PRODUCT_4       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4 = -          |
    |ID_PRODUCT_5       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5 = -          |
    +--------------------------------+

    *--------------------------------+
    |ID                 = 2          |
    |DATE               = 2017-02-03 |
    |ID_PRODUCT_1       = 1003       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1 = 1400       |
    |ID_PRODUCT_2       = 1001       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2 = 1000       |
    |ID_PRODUCT_3       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3 = -          |
    |ID_PRODUCT_4       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4 = -          |
    |ID_PRODUCT_5       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5 = -          |
    +--------------------------------+
    *--------------------------------+
    |ID                 = 3          |
    |DATE               = 2017-02-03 |
    |ID_PRODUCT_1       = 1002       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1 = 1400       |
    |ID_PRODUCT_2       = 1003       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2 = 600        |
    |ID_PRODUCT_3       = 1001       |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3 = 200        |
    |ID_PRODUCT_4       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4 = -          |
    |ID_PRODUCT_5       = -          |
    |QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5 = -          |
    +--------------------------------+
```

Lo que necesito es sumar la cantidad de cada producto, sin importar en qué campo haya sido registrado, y al final este sería el resultado:

```
    +--------------------------------+
    |SUM(PRODUCT WITH ID 1001) = 2600|
    |SUM(PRODUCT WITH ID 1002) = 2000|
    |SUM(PRODUCT WITH ID 1003) = 2000|
    +--------------------------------+
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas. Sería genial si pudieras escribir tu pregunta en español :) Todos aquí lo hablamos. (Ademas es una regla de este sitio :P)

Comment: Hegel, edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve]. De otra manera parece que estás pidiendo que te resuelvan tu tarea, y eso escapa del alcance del sitio, por que es demasiado.

Comment: El diseño de tu tabla si no lo es, será  fácilmente un rompecabezas. Tendrías que leer cada columna para ir buscando id por id y sumar las cantidades. Y no digamos nada si en lugar de tener 5 columnas en la misma tabla para un mismo tipo de dato, tuvieras 10 ó 20 ó 50. Se puede hacer, pero la informática existe para facilitar las cosas, no para complicarlas. Con dos o tres tablas (productos, pedidos) se resuelve lo que planteas de una manera limpia y organizada, sin columnas del tipo: producto1, producto2, producto3, producto100. Y no te digo nada si te piden el nombre, el precio, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el operador UNION ALL para poner las columnas una después de otra, por horrible que sea.

```
SELECT ID_PRODUCT_1 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
  UNION ALL
SELECT ID_PRODUCT_2 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
  UNION ALL
SELECT ID_PRODUCT_3 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
  UNION ALL
SELECT ID_PRODUCT_4 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
  UNION ALL
SELECT ID_PRODUCT_5 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
```

(**PD1**: esto yo lo metería en una vista, para no tener que poner esta query tan fea en todo el código)

(**PD2**: en realidad no es necesario que las columnas se llamen igual al hacer un UNION, basta con que sean del mismo tipo, en tu caso integer. Escribí la query asi para que se entienda mejor qué estoy haciendo )

eso te da un resultado de la forma:

```
id_product  quantity
1001        1400
1002        600
1003        1400 
1001        1000
1002        1400
1003        600
1002        200
```

(acá podrías tener también la fecha, que puede ser útil para efectos futuros)

Entonces puedes operar sobre ese resultado haciendo (este será un bloque largo)

```
SELECT id_product, SUM(quantity) FROM 
  (
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_1 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_1 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_2 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_2 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_3 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_3 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_4 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_4 as quantity FROM MITABLA;
    UNION ALL
  SELECT ID_PRODUCT_5 as id_product, QUANTITY_PRODUCT_5 as quantity FROM MITABLA;

  ) supertabla
GROUP BY id_product
```

Ahora, por qué UNION ALL y no UNION? Eso es porque UNION solo te hace un distinct, y en tu esquema no tiene nada de malo que haya dos ventas del producto 1001 por la misma cantidad, y no queremos dejar sólo las combinaciones únicas.

Como dijo @mejiapereznestor, este es un esquema muy irregular, y está lejos del concepto de normalización, para empezar porque ¿Qué pasa si alguien compra más de 5 productos de una sola vez? ¿Habría que hacerle una segunda factura?

De todos modos, a veces uno toma en sus manos un proyecto legacy y no tiene otra opción que jugar con esas reglas, porque la lógica de negocios está tan acoplada al modelo de datos que no puedes tocar ninguna pieza a riesgo de que se rompa todo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

creo que la lógica de tu tabla es incorrecta. te muestro un ejemplo,  tu tabla de registros quedaría de la siguiente manera para esto necesitaras 2 tablas :
Esta seria la primera tabla:
Tabla productos:

```
+-----------------+
|id               |
|producto         |
+-----------------+
```

la segunda tabla seria la sig.
tabla registros:

```
+-----------------+
|id               |
|fkidProducto     |//fkidProducto es el id del producto de la tabla anterior
|cantidad         |
|date             |
+-----------------+
```

ya que tienes estas dos tablas haces lo sig.
agregas los 5 productos a tu tabla productos.
supongamos que tienes estos registros en la primera tabla

```
+---------------+
|id   |producto |
+---------------+
|1    |jabon    |
|2    |aceite   |
|3    |pasta    |
|4    |atun     |
|5    |gelatina |
+---------------+
```

y cuando quieras agregar una entrada a tu tabla registro
insertas (id,Fkidproducto,cantidad,fecha)

entonces tus registros quedarian de  esta manera:

```
  *----------------------------------------------------------+
    |ID           |  FkidProduncto |   cantidad | fecha      |
    |    1        |      1         |     10     | 2017-02-03 |
    |    2        |      4         |      5     | 2017-02-03 |
    |    3        |      5         |    20      |2017-02-03  |
    |    4        |      5         |    3       |2017-02-03  |
    +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

entonces y asi sucesivamente para agregar entradas en tu tabla registros

ya que tienes esto es haces tu consulta select correspondiente

```
select sum(cantidad) where FkidProducto=5
```

tomando en cuenta los valores que te puse de ejemplo la consulta deberia regresarte `23`

espero que pueda resolver tu problema